Only one tkinter notebook frame creates. (using class)
I trying to use class to create multiple tkinter notebook tabs. But I can only make one tab at once.
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Tabs:
    current_tab = Frame(notebook)
    current_entry = None
    current_from = StringVar()
    current_to = StringVar()
    result = StringVar()

    def __init__(self, name: str, units,calc_mode: str):
        self.name = name
        self.units = units
        self.calc_mode = calc_mode
    

    def create_frame(self):
        notebook.add(self.current_tab, text=self.name)
        Label(self.current_tab, text=self.name, font=("Arial", 30, "bold"), pady=20, padx=60).grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3)
        Label(self.current_tab, text="From: ", font=("Arial", 18, "bold")).grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.current_entry = Entry(self.current_tab, font="arial")
        self.current_entry.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.current_from.set("Select")
        OptionMenu(self.current_tab,self.current_from,*self.units.keys()).grid(row=1, column=3)
        Label(self.current_tab, text="To: ", font=("Arial", 18, "bold")).grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.current_to.set("Select")
        OptionMenu(self.current_tab, self.current_to, *self.units.keys()).grid(row=2, column=2)
        Label(self.current_tab, text="Result: ", font=("Arial", 18, "bold", "italic"), width=10).grid(row=4,column=0)
        self.result.set("")
        print_result = Label(self.current_tab, textvariable=self.result, font=("Arial", 28, "bold"))
        print_result.grid(row=4, column=2)
        Button(self.current_tab, text="Calculate", font=("Arial", 18, "italic"), pady=4, command=self.calculate).grid(row=3,column=2)

And it always shows the last one (for example the length tab here)
tempertaure_tab = Tabs("Temperature",temp_units,"temperature")
tempertaure_tab.create_frame()
length_tab = Tabs("Length",length_units,"normal")
length_tab.create_frame()

So that is my problem.

current_tab and similar names are class attributes - exactly one value exists for each of them, no matter how many instances of the class you create.  Things that you want to be distinct for each instance need to be instance attributes, typically created in the .__init__() method.

Thanks, its working int the init method
